Exercise 7-35 in "modern mathematical statistics with applications"
I have a question regarding this exercise:
Twenty identical components are put on test. The lifetime distribution of each is exponential with parameter $\lambda$. The experimenter then leaves the test facility unmonitored. On her return 24h later, the experimenter immediately terminates the test after noticing that $y = 15$ of the 20 components are still in operation (so 5 have failed). Derive the MLE of $\lambda$. [Hint: Let $Y \sim Bin(n,p)$. What is the MLE of p? Now notice that $p = P(X_i \geq 24)$, where $X_i$ is exponentially distributed. This relates $\lambda$ to p, so the former can be estimated once the latter has been.]
I have come to understand that the likelihood function is $L(p) = {n \choose y}p^y(1-p)^{n-y}$. This will lead to the numerical answer in the "answers to exercises" in the text. It will also give the MLE $\hat{p}=\frac{Y}{n}$, which is very intuitive.
But I fully understand the reason for $L(p) = {n \choose y}p^y(1-p)^{n-y}$ instead of $L(p) = \prod {n \choose y_i}p^y(1-p)^{n-y_i}$ which is the "usual" way to set up the likelihood. The likelihood is the product of the individual PDFs (if they are independent of each other). But, here $Y$ will be count, and not the individual outcome of each components, so then it is only one function in the likelihood...
What I actually don't understand is why you start with 20 trials, and begin the reasoning with just one ($Y$, the count). I guess you could do that because it is Bernoulli trials (success/fail), and the count of n Bernoulli trials is binomial...?
Perhaps I answered my own question, now, but this exercise was a bit confusing to get my head around. But, I guess the short answer here is that there is only ONE sample, the count, and that I should not get confused by the 20 trials...?
